# Access Internet with Cisco 877

Tags: networking, router, adsl, adsl2+

I'm hopeful that a Cisco specialist will see this.

I am starting down the path of doing a CCNA qualification, and have purchased a Cisco 877W-G-A-K9 to practice on (so I can actually use it "live").  I have set up Bridge Groups etc and have managed to access my NAS etc via Wireless.  The inside network works just fine.

However I CANNOT access the internet; by that I mean the CD light flashes and then goes solid, indicating I have recognised and (I think ...) authenticated to my line.

However, I do NOT get a PPPoE session established, my PPP light stays ominously dark.

I have scoured the internet, Cisco manuals and various possible configurations on different pages and nothing seems to work.  So I am hoping someone with some Cisco experience can take a look at my running-config and tell me what the issue is.

I suspect it lies in the connection between my Dialer and the ATM port and is quite possibly to do with incorrectly configured DNS but I need help. The outside IP address and DNS is set as my ISP specifies a static IP address and primary / secondary DNS addresses (and I am not convinced I have set up the dns correctly anyway ... like I said - just starting out down the CCNA path)

Please could someone take a look at my running-config and offer some advice?

```
Current configuration : 4621 bytes  
!  
version 12.4  
no service pad  
service timestamps debug datetime msec  
service timestamps log datetime msec  
service password-encryption  
!  
hostname Cisco877  
!  
boot-start-marker  
boot-end-marker  
!  
enable secret 5 *****************************  
!  
no aaa new-model  
!  
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-152119483  
 enrollment selfsigned  
 subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-152119483  
 revocation-check none  
 rsakeypair TP-self-signed-152119483  
!  
!  
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-152119483  
 certificate self-signed 01  
  30820251 308201BA A0030201 02020101 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 04050030  
  30312E30 2C060355 04031325 494F532D 53656C66 2D536967 6E65642D 43657274  
  69666963 6174652D 31353231 31393438 33301E17 0D303230 33303130 30323431  
  385A170D 32303031 30313030 30303030 5A303031 2E302C06 03550403 1325494F  
  532D5365 6C662D53 69676E65 642D4365 72746966 69636174 652D3135 32313139  
  34383330 819F300D 06092A86 4886F70D 01010105 0003818D 00308189 02818100  
  A3CD4BBC 82A01A88 5D40A1B5 6A75680A ABE77A66 3AD8F7CA CC4CB032 3611F8B0  
  19074D33 66752E15 215E47DA 13DB1CB3 2DDDEE07 52FF9109 657A8BEB 0BBD34CA  
  F080A990 026C8CA3 2CC2C6A1 6668C88E 4DE25C2B 22017FB5 A32718DC 7DE81FFD  
  BAEEEA5E CE334574 2A6676D4 FB206F7A 7BC292B3 E67A56F1 D736C80A FBF51E6F  
  02030100 01A37B30 79300F06 03551D13 0101FF04 05300301 01FF3026 0603551D  
  11041F30 1D821B43 6973636F 3837372E 6E657470 6F70756C 61726573 2E6C6F63  
  616C301F 0603551D 23041830 16801490 B0B8513E F48EE6D3 181AEC75 BFFBE711  
  5A191330 1D060355 1D0E0416 041490B0 B8513EF4 8EE6D318 1AEC75BF FBE7115A  
  1913300D 06092A86 4886F70D 01010405 00038181 009D7AAC 382DFE78 CD2800F8  
  92785082 70244016 8C714314 3A54D019 26D244B1 A4447FA6 31ECB622 919A8124  
  BC902E2D 60D93CF0 65552084 6A4D2B5E 5CE1CAFD 9F5DE3A9 9836A6BB AF4A77AC  
  0EE97396 34654776 A4452399 494BAB4A BEB59405 15D52F62 5DAFBDC6 771E4701  
  609E0367 3D2E888A 4206D12F AEED8014 68B32B7B 7D  
        quit  
dot11 syslog  
!  
dot11 ssid Corazon  
   vlan 1  
   authentication open  
   authentication key-management wpa  
   guest-mode  
   wpa-psk ascii 7 *****************************  
!  
no ip source-route  
ip cef  
no ip dhcp use vrf connected  
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.15  
!  
ip dhcp pool dpool1  
   import all  
   network 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0  
   default-router 192.168.0.1  
   dns-server 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220  
   update arp  
!  
!  
ip auth-proxy max-nodata-conns 3  
ip admission max-nodata-conns 3  
no ip domain lookup  
ip domain name belong.com.au  
ip name-server 208.67.222.222  
ip name-server 208.67.220.220  
!  
!  
!  
!  
!  
archive  
 log config  
  hidekeys  
!  
!  
!  
bridge irb  
!  
!  
interface ATM0  
 description ----- ADSL Connection ----  
 no ip address  
 ip virtual-reassembly  
 no atm ilmi-keepalive  
 pvc 8/35  
  tx-ring-limit 3  
  encapsulation aal5snap  
  pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1  
 !  
 dsl operating-mode auto  
!  
interface FastEthernet0  
!  
interface FastEthernet1  
!  
interface FastEthernet2  
!  
interface FastEthernet3  
!  
interface Dot11Radio0  
 no ip address  
 !  
 encryption vlan 1 mode ciphers aes-ccm  
 !  
 encryption mode ciphers aes-ccm  
 !  
 broadcast-key vlan 1 change 45  
 !  
 !  
 ssid Corazon  
 !  
 speed basic-1.0 basic-2.0 basic-5.5 6.0 9.0 basic-11.0 12.0 18.0 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0  
 station-role root  
 no cdp enable  
!  
interface Dot11Radio0.1   
 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native  
 ip virtual-reassembly  
 no cdp enable  
 bridge-group 1  
 bridge-group 1 subscriber-loop-control  
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled  
 bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source  
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning  
 no bridge-group 1 unicast-flooding  
!  
interface Vlan1  
 no ip address  
 ip virtual-reassembly  
 bridge-group 1  
!  
interface Dialer0  
 description ---- ADSL ----  
 ip address 144.138.131.214 255.255.255.0  
 ip mtu 1492  
 ip nat outside  
 ip virtual-reassembly  
 encapsulation ppp  
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1420  
 dialer pool 1   
 dialer-group 1  
 no cdp enable  
 ppp authentication chap  
 ppp chap hostname 571549@belong.com.au  
 ppp chap password 7 *****************************  
!  
interface BVI1  
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0  
 ip nat inside  
 ip virtual-reassembly  
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1420  
!  
ip forward-protocol nd  
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer0  
!  
no ip http server  
no ip http secure-server  
ip nat inside source list NAT interface Dialer0 overload  
!  
ip access-list extended NAT  
 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 any  
!  
dialer-list 1 protocol ip permit  
!  
!  
!  
control-plane  
!  
bridge 1 protocol ieee  
bridge 1 route ip  
!  
line con 0  
 password 7 10480518161F43  
 logging synchronous  
 login  
 no modem enable  
line aux 0  
line vty 0 4  
 password 7 *****************************  
 logging synchronous  
 login local  
 transport input ssh  
!  
scheduler max-task-time 5000  
end
```

-------------- UPDATE --------------

I ran debug ppp authentication from console and got following output:

```
Cisco877#  
*Mar 1 00:32:19.311: %DIALER-6-BIND: Interface Vi1 bound to profile Di0  
*Mar 1 00:32:19.311: Vi1 PPP: Using dialer call direction  
*Mar 1 00:32:19.311: Vi1 PPP: Treating connection as a callout  
*Mar 1 00:32:19.311: Vi1 PPP: Session handle[AC000017] Session id[0]  
*Mar 1 00:32:19.311: Vi1 PPP: Authorization required  
Cisco877#  
*Mar 1 00:32:19.315: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Virtual-Access1, changed state to up  
Cisco877#  
*Mar 1 00:32:23.687: %DIALER-6-UNBIND: Interface Vi1 unbound from profile Di0  
Cisco877#  
*Mar 1 00:32:23.691: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Virtual-Access1, changed state to down
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this, or with a similar problem, I removed the line `ppp authenticate chap` from Dialer 0 and it immediately logged on.

I now have an "interesting" DNS issue, but that's a separate thread!